# Поиск по строкам json в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, json

Дан файл json - data.json. данные с сайта через парсинг постоянно обновляются. В нем находятся примерно такие данные:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 60288,
            "name": "Моя пиратская свадьба",
            "year": 2023,
            "quality": "FHD (1080p)",
            "genre": "Комедия, Боевик, Мелодрама",
            "type": "Фильмы",
            "country": "США",
        },
        {
            "id": 62976,
            "name": "Подземный дьявол",
            "year": 2023,
            "quality": "FHD (1080p)",
            "genre": "Ужасы",
            "type": "Фильмы",
            "country": "США",
        },
        {
            "id": 63002,
            "name": "Бескрайний бассейн",
            "year": 2023,
            "quality": "FHD (1080p)",
            "genre": "Ужасы, Фантастика, Детектив, Триллер",
            "type": "Фильмы",
            "country": "Канада, Франция, Венгрия",
        },
        {
            "id": 62362,
            "name": "Сволочи",
            "year": 2023,
            "quality": "TS",
            "genre": "Криминал, Комедия, Боевик, Триллер",
            "type": "Фильмы",
            "country": "Индия",
        },
        {
            "id": 63007,
            "name": "Памела: История любви",
            "year": 2023,
            "quality": "FHD (1080p)",
            "genre": "Документальный, Биографический",
            "type": "Фильмы",
            "country": "США",
        },
        {
            "id": 63028,
            "name": "Олег Яковлев. Чужой",
            "year": 2023,
            "quality": "FHD (1080p)",
            "genre": "Документальный, Биографический",
            "type": "Фильмы",
            "country": "Россия",
        }

    ]
}
```

Есть переменная в нее каждый цикл выгружается новый id, например `film_id=63028`.

Делаю проверку  блоков по id уже записанных в файл:

```
with open ('data.json', 'r', encoding='utf8') as file:
    datafilm = json.load(file)
    for id in datafilm['data']:
        try:                                      
            if film_id == id['id']:                                   
                print(есть в бд)   
            except KeyError:
               print("ID doesn't exist")
```

и скрипт проходя цикл каждый раз с новым id производит поиск по всей бд и в консоль что в data.json есть строка с этим id, находит строку выводит что она есть и происходит следующий цикл поиска.

но мне нужно чтобы в случае если в бд нет id из цикличной переменной то происходило одинарное событие типа print(id в бд нет)

для этого я добавил в код

```
with open ('news_films.json', 'r', encoding='utf8') as file:
    datafilm = json.load(file)
    for id in datafilm['data']:
        try:                                      
            if film_id == id['id']:                                   
                print("есть в бд")
            else:
                print("нет в бд")     
        except KeyError:
               print("ID doesn't exist")
```

в итоге скрипт проходит по каждой строке id и выводит "нет в бд"  консоль выводит "нет в бд" столько раз сколько строк бд

как в else: реализовать, чтобы скрипт тихо проходил по всем строкам сравнивал все id с переменной и в случае полного отсутствия id в бд 1 раз выводил "нет в бд"?

Comment: Например, выше for сделать переменную isBd = 0, и там где сейчас пишите print("нет в бд")  там делать isBd = 1, и после всего for проверяете, если isBd == 0 то пишите print("нет в бд")

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте так:

```
# эту часть можно сделать один раз
with open ('data.json', 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
    datafilm = json.load(f)
data_ids = set(r['id'] for r in datafilm['data'] if 'id' in r)

# эта проверка может быть сделана много раз для разных film_id
# она очень быстрая
if film_id in data_ids:                                   
    print('есть в бд')   
else:
    print('нет в бд')
```

Comment: Спасибо дружище! заработало. 3 дня голову ломал

Answer (score 0):

**Вариант 1**
Можно использовать `else:` для `for`, а также `.get()` для словаря

```
import json

json_text = '''{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 60288,
            "name": "Моя пиратская свадьба",
            "year": 2023,
            "quality": "FHD (1080p)",
            "genre": "Комедия, Боевик, Мелодрама",
            "type": "Фильмы",
            "country": "США"
        },
        {
            "id": 62976,
            "name": "Подземный дьявол",
            "year": 2023,
            "quality": "FHD (1080p)",
            "genre": "Ужасы",
            "type": "Фильмы",
            "country": "США"
        },
        {
            "id": 63002,
            "name": "Бескрайний бассейн",
            "year": 2023,
            "quality": "FHD (1080p)",
            "genre": "Ужасы, Фантастика, Детектив, Триллер",
            "type": "Фильмы",
            "country": "Канада, Франция, Венгрия"
        },
        {
            "id": 62362,
            "name": "Сволочи",
            "year": 2023,
            "quality": "TS",
            "genre": "Криминал, Комедия, Боевик, Триллер",
            "type": "Фильмы",
            "country": "Индия"
        },
        {
            "id": 63007,
            "name": "Памела: История любви",
            "year": 2023,
            "quality": "FHD (1080p)",
            "genre": "Документальный, Биографический",
            "type": "Фильмы",
            "country": "США"
        },
        {
            "id": 63028,
            "name": "Олег Яковлев. Чужой",
            "year": 2023,
            "quality": "FHD (1080p)",
            "genre": "Документальный, Биографический",
            "type": "Фильмы",
            "country": "Россия"
        }
    ]
}'''
film_id = 63029
datafilm = json.loads(json_text)
for id in datafilm['data']:
    if film_id == id.get('id'):
        print(f'id {film_id} есть в БД')
        break
else:
    print(f'id {film_id} нет в БД')
```

```
id 63029 нет в БД
```

**Вариант 2** - c использованием `pandas`

```
import pandas as pd

film_id = 63029
datafilm = pd.read_json(json_text)
if datafilm['data'].str['id'].isin([film_id]).any():
    print(f'id {film_id} есть в БД')
else:
    print(f'id {film_id} нет в БД')
```